Fourier uncertainty principle
When working on DSP of audio signals, I personnaly "experience" the Fourier uncertainty principle in this way:
When doing a STFT / a spectrogram, you have to choose a tradeoff between time-domain precision and frequency-domain precision. You cannot have both at the same time. If good temporal precision, the frequency localization will be weak, and vice versa.
I think this is called "Fourier uncertainty principle" in the fact we cannot have both precise localization (or compact support) for a function $f(t)$ and for its Fourier transform $\hat{f}(t)$.
We often hear that the "Heisenberg uncertainty principle" is the same in quantum mechanics : impossible to have good position localization and velocity precision at the same time.
Question: are "Fourier uncertainty principle" and "Heisenberg uncertainty principle" only vaguely linked in the general "spirit" of the principle?
Or are they really mathematically very close concepts (for example, because the Heisenberg uncertainty principle uses Fourier in its math description)?
TL;DR: are Heisenberg and Fourier uncertainty principles close only in "hand waving" arguments or also in formalized math?

I could be way off on this, but I’m pretty sure the uncertainty principle is just that, a principle based on observation. There are different derivations for different pairs of physical properties. For harmonic analysis, Benedick’s theorem proves you cannot have a time-limited and band-limited function. The Gabor limit connects this to the uncertainty principle.

Does this answer satisfy you? For a different viewpoint, see here.
